# How to approach creating musical instrument sounds?

Tags: java, android

I've started to develop an application that allows the user to play notes on instruments. In particular, traditional Balinese instruments. As with many instruments, they have a certain amount of notes within an octave. Now I am completely out of my depth here on how to get started about the musical theory. My initial plan is to simply record the sounds of the different notes being played and play them back, but this seems a bit of a poor man's approach. The goal of the application is to be able to practice, the sound doesn't have to be perfect, but is there some middle ground to take? For example, could I record a single note as a wave file and play it at a different pitch to emulate being able to play all notes?
The application will be an Android app in Java and I know it's technically doable to change pitch of a wave file but I am not so much looking at the technical solution as to whether this is a good approach to begin with.

Comment: `is there some middle ground to take?` -- Roland discovered years ago that they could sample the initial attack of a musical instrument note while  synthesizing the remaining waveform, and the resulting sound is more realistic than synthesis alone can provide.

Comment: `Could I record a single note as a wave file and play it at a different pitch to emulate being able to play all notes?` -- Yes, if you don't bend the pitch too much.  Most samplers that use this technique provide samples for e.g. every fifth note, and then bend those notes to fill in the remaining notes.

Comment: Just to make sure, by not bending too much you mean staying relatively close to the original frequency right? Btw I should have been more clear in my post, the sound doesn't have to be super high quality, the main goal is simple practice and becoming familiar with the sound.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  Sampling every fifth note means you only need 1/5 the samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording acoustic instruments is difficult. Producing believable sound by using perfectly recorded samples is very difficult. Large companies like Yamaha and Roland have been working for decades finding solutions to the same problem you're facing.

However, I think your approach will work as long as you don't need to produce realistic sounds.

Designwise you could begin with each Instrument having a SoundMap associated with it.

The SoundMap should have a method

```
public Sound get(Note note)
```

A Note object should hold all information about a musical note on a score. The Sound object should consist of all data required to play the note using any sound API, like a reference to the sample and the required pitch bend.

This basic design would allow you to build the SoundMap for each instrument individually and it would also leave room for improvements. You could have as many samples for each instrument as you find necessary, be it one sample for every note or one sample for five notes. You could also add more information both to the Sound class and to the Note class to allow different samples for different volumes etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my rather old piano has high quality recordings of every single note, at 8 different volume levels each (because a loud not isn't just louder, it also sounds different). Recording every fifth note only will sound awful - you will very much notice the jumps between the different recordings, and that *does* reduce the fun.

Not sure how you would let the user play at different volumes.

Comment: It's an Android app; resources are limited.